# ABCD is a square. The line joining mid point of AB to D and the line joining the mid point of CD to A meet at G. Is BGC an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Basically, the figure looks like this:
[image: Figure]

E is mid point of AB and F is mid point of CD.
Intuitively, BGC looks like an equilateral triangle, although I am not able to find the correct mathematical proof. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, but no cigar. If the altitude is drawn from $G$ to $\overline{BC}$ is measures $3/4$ of the base, whereas this ratiowould he $\sqrt3/2$ for an actual equilateral triangle.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta BGC$ definitely does not look like an equilateral triangle. If the triangle is equilateral then the length of side $BG$ should equal the length of side $AB$ and triangle $\Delta ABG$ should be isoceles. In this case the angle $\angle FAD=15^\circ$ but your $\angle FAD=\tan^{-1}0.5\approx 26.5^\circ$.

You should be able to rotate the triangle $30^\circ$ anticlockwise around point $B$ and have $BG$ match into $AB$ for an equilateral triangle.